# empty space in the second fraction of grid-template-column in big screen layout

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z600q.jpg)

So, i am trying to create my layout for big screens (min-width:768px). Yet, when I set grid-template-columns as 1fr 1fr, there is empty space in the second column for both divs.

```
/* about */

.about-container{
    padding: 3rem;
    max-width: 90vw;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    .about{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
}

.about_picture_1{
    width: 100%;
display: block;
height: 100%;
border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```
<div class="about-container">
<div class="about">
  <div class="column_about_1">
    <h2>Our Story</h2>
      <p class="about_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, minus. Animi adipisci perspiciatis, quae aspernatur fugiat odit incidunt officia nemo enim consequuntur quas cupiditate obcaecati hic, doloremque corrupti labore quidem?</p>
      <div class="about_picture">
        <img src="img/bravo.jpg" class="about_picture_1" alt="">
      </div>


      <div class="column_about_2">
      <h2>Our Story</h2>
      <p class="about_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, minus. Animi adipisci perspiciatis, quae aspernatur fugiat odit incidunt officia nemo enim consequuntur quas cupiditate obcaecati hic, doloremque corrupti labore quidem?</p>
      <img src="img/pizzafork.jpg" class="about_picture_1" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you want to put 2 column vertically or horizontally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should move the display:grid css rule in "about" class outside of media query and set the grid areas outside then for 768px and up for big screens set the grid template areas for 2 columns. Here's my sample css code that I made:

```
.about-container{
    padding: 3rem;
    max-width: 90vw;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}

.about {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
    "col1 col1"
    "col2 col2";
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    .about{
        grid-template-areas:
        "col1 col2"
        "col1 col2";
    }
}

.about_picture_1{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.column_about_1 {
    grid-area: col1;
}

.column_about_2 {
    grid-area: col2;
}
```

Comment: I copied your code and fixed the html structure as well. It's working fine now on my end.

Comment: @derek Hi I think you also need to restructure your html that's why it isn't working on your end? found out that you missed closing divs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your html structure that I updated/fixed.

```
<div class="about-container">
    <div class="about">
        <div class="column_about_1">
            <h2>Our Story</h2>
              <p class="about_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, minus. Animi adipisci perspiciatis, quae aspernatur fugiat odit incidunt officia nemo enim consequuntur quas cupiditate obcaecati hic, doloremque corrupti labore quidem?</p>
              <div class="about_picture">
                <img src="img/bravo.jpg" class="about_picture_1" alt="">
              </div>
       </div>
       <div class="column_about_2">

            <h2>Our Story</h2>
            <p class="about_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, minus. Animi adipisci perspiciatis, quae aspernatur fugiat odit incidunt officia nemo enim consequuntur quas cupiditate obcaecati hic, doloremque corrupti labore quidem?</p>
            <div>
              <img src="img/pizzafork.jpg" class="about_picture_1" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```